# Why changing the text on the button fails?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a tiny snippet with a button that toggles the visibility of a div and is supposed to toggle the label on the button. Unfortunately, the label changing does not work. I have tried `html` and `text` to no avail. How can I fix it?

JS:

```
$('.toc_button').click(function(){
    an_ID = 'div_' + this.id;
    var an_element = document.getElementById(an_ID);
    if (an_element.style.display === "none") {
            an_element.style.display = "inline";
            alert(this.id + "2");
        this.text("-");
        alert("3");
    } else {
          an_element.style.display = "none";
        alert(this.id + "5");
        this.text("+").button("refresh");
        alert("6");
    }
})
```

HTML:

```
<button class="toc_button" id="button_toc_id" type="button">+</button><br>
<div class='div_toc_initial' id='div_button_toc_id'>dhfgdh</div>
```

The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yu51a5/fdvm2xr4/10/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `this.text()`. `.text()` can be used on a jquery object, so you need `$(this).text()`

Also you can't use `.button("refresh");` after `$(this).text()`

Hint: Next time you face a problem remember to check the console log. What would most likely tell you the error.

Comment: Thanks! Would you know why this question was downvoted?

Comment: @YuliaV No problem. Regarding the downvote, I can't tell you for sure why, but i guess it's becasue you should have debugged it yourself, like i said check the console log.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $(this).html("hello") to replace the content of an element

Comment: Given the example the OP has provided, I would be more correct to use `$(this).text()`